# attach event to object/array

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say for you example you have this array

```
 //Defined at the top of your class
 myArray = [];
 //Then somewhere else in the code
 myArray["unique_id"] = {example: true, example2: false, etc..};
 //somewhere else
 delete myArray["unique_id"];
```

Could it be possible to have something like this:

```
//when adding
myArray["unique_id"] = {example: true, example2: false, etc..};
myArray.trigger("array:update");
//when deleting
delete myArray["unique_id"];
myArray.trigger("array:delete");

//and in a different file or somewhere else down the path
myArray.on("array:update", function(){
   //do stuff
});

//and in a different file or somewhere else down the path
myArray.on("array:delete", function(){
   //do stuff
});
```

I like the custom event system and I was wondering if thats something possible. Didn't find examples on the documentation of this specific application. 
Basically attaching custom events to array/objects and not necessarily dom elements.

Comment: No this is not possible to do without manually calling trigger on update or manually calling delete on deletion. You can wrap these behaviors in a single call and then when you make the call it all happens at once, but it still requires custom setup.

Comment: What if I created a dummy div like `$("<div>")` and then listen to my custom events on it. Would that be an acceptable hack ?

Comment: Are you sure you want to use an `Array`?  `delete myArray["unique_id"];` looks like you want to use a regular object. Arrays have the items stored with an index `0..n`, and not a string as index and removing an elment from an Array is not done using `delete`.

Comment: Just change the first line with {}. I always forget the distinction as from php, array are versatile.

Comment: The you moste likely look for [EventEmitter3](https://github.com/primus/eventemitter3). But you need to `trigger` the `delete`,`update` events manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible using a [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy), but you'll have to make the object emulate an [`EventEmitter`](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_class_eventemitter) first:

```js
//Defined at the top of your class
let myObject = {};

//Emulate EventEmitter
myObject._events = {};
myObject.emit = function emit(event, ...args) {
  (this._events[event] || []).forEach(callback => {
    callback.apply(this, args);
  });
};
myObject.on = function on(event, callback) {
  if (!this._events[event]) {
    this._events[event] = [];
  }

  this._events[event].push(callback);
};

//Define Proxy
let myProxy = new Proxy(myObject, {
  set(target, name, value) {
    target.emit('update', name, value);
    return (target[name] = value);
  },
  deleteProperty(target, name) {
    target.emit('delete', name);
    return (delete target[name]);
  }
});

//and in a different file or somewhere else down the path
myObject.on('update', function(name, value) {
  console.log('update', this, name, value);
});

//and in a different file or somewhere else down the path
myObject.on('delete', function(name) {
  console.log('delete', this, name);
});

//Then somewhere else in the code
myProxy["unique_id"] = {
  example: true,
  example2: false
};
//somewhere else
delete myProxy["unique_id"];
```